# Same URL scrapes different data when run from settings

Tags: import.io

I'm trying to scrape some data and when I run New Extractor for first time with [this url](http://www.blocket.se/skane/bilar?ca=23&cg=1020&st=s&l=0&w=1&cb=2&cbl1=2) it returns list of cars exactly what I see. However when I save it and run it from the settings, exactly same link, I get completely different results, that seem unfiltered. I can't figure out why it's different. Link is the same and has filters in it set.

Comment: Stack overflow isn't the best place for this kind of question. Feel free to visit https://www.import.io/help/

Comment: Trying to via many channels. I know this might not seem like the best place, but they also suggest SO. I was hoping some are looking through the issues related to their keyword. Fact that same url extracts different data, feels like a big bug or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The import.io engineering team have applied a fix to this issue!

Please try again and let us know if you have any more problems.